# Bracket Highlighter does not show up

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Im running into some problems when im trying to install the bracket hightlighter in sublime. If I hit CMD/Shift/P I select "Package control: install package". But then I do not get an option to install Bracket Highlighter. This is what is see: https://www.flickr.com/photos/113328996@N07/15930354698/

Do I have to install something somewhere to get this to show up?

Answer (score 0):

You may already have BracketHighlighter installed, as this is the most common reason for a package not showing up in the install menu. Go to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User` and see if it is in the list of installed packages. If it is, you can start configuring it by copying the entire contents of `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Bracket Highlighter -> Settings-Default` to `Settings-User`. You can now close the `Default` tab and make your changes to the `User` file.

If for some reason it is not listed as installed, open `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` and see if there is a folder named `Bracket Highlighter`. If there is, try deleting it, then try to install the package again.

If neither of the above options work, the final thing to try is deleting and reinstalling Package Control. The instructions for doing so are [here](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/troubleshooting#Purging_Old_Versions). Make sure when you're reinstalling that you use the [ST2](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2) code.

Good luck!